# toggling css classes using knockout

Tags: jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I am trying to do some like this. is it a valid syntax? I am checking for some flag value and toggling b/w two css classes?

```
<div data-bind="visible:'anchorJobContractor'===JobDetail_SelctedTab(), css:IsTabsCollapsed ? TabCollapsed : TabExpanded"></div>
```

First part visible dataBinding  works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try encasing the logic for CSS within braces like this:

```
<div data-bind="visible:'anchorJobContractor'===JobDetail_SelctedTab(), css: { IsTabsCollapsed ? TabCollapsed : TabExpanded }"></div>
```

Either that or you could move the logic into your javascript rather than doing it in the HTML by using a computed value.

```
viewModel.myCssClass = ko.computed(function() {
    return IsTabsCollapsed ? "TabCollapsed" : "TabExpanded";
}, viewModel);


<div data-bind="visible:'anchorJobContractor'===JobDetail_SelctedTab(), css: myCssClass"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one possible syntax for **css** binding:

```
<div data-bind="css: { TabCollapsed: IsTabsCollapsed, TabExpanded: !IsTabsCollapsed() }"></div>
```

See also documentation at: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

If IsTabsCollapsed is an observable you have to do:

```
IsTabsCollapsed() ? TabCollapsed : TabExpanded
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS binding with a computed observable like this.

```
<div data-bind="css: TabClass">
   ...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        IsTabsCollapsed: ko.observable(false);
    };
    viewModel.TabClass = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.IsTabsCollapsed() ? "TabCollapsed " : "TabExpanded";
    }, viewModel);
</script>
```

It's not the smallest and cleanest way to achieve what you want, but it's really easy to manage and alter, and very understandable.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Quick and dirty version*

I needed a quick and dirty way to apply a class to a debugging panel, and came up with the following.

I recommend this version only for debugging, and it only works if you are also using jQuery.

```
<div class="debug-only knockout-debug-panel" 
            data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('transparent'); }">

</div>

.transparent { opacity: .5; }
```

Knockout has a function `toggleDomNodeCssClass`, but unfortuntely it requires a boolean whether to add or remove the class.